# Display data horizontally with subtotal

Tags: crystal-reports

I am modifying the crystal report design to display the data horizontally.
Here are the sample data:
[image: Sample Data]

I would need to group the data by Year and then Class, and the final output for the Crystal report should be as follows:

[image: Final Output]

I would show this result in one page by landscape orientation. Please help advise how can I achieve this with Crystal Report. I have searched for Cross-tab function, but I still get no idea how to show the group header and sub-total. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: cross  tab should help you..... where are you facing issue in cross tab?

Comment: hi Siva, I have no idea how to display "Mark 1", "Mark 2", "Mark 3" and "Mark 4" as the second column like the second picture shown. Could you advise?